# Grab Clipboard data on page load

Tags: php, javascript, copy-paste

Im trying to create a script that will grab the users clipboard data on pageload, and show up in a textbox where they can press Submit.

Ive looked all over google and can not find the solution. I was wondering if this is possible?

Answer (score 1):

Afaik it's not possible for security reasons - imagine the case that you just copy-and-pasted some password and a website steals it.

Comment: ah didn't really assume something like this when asking :P
I guess I have to make the users Ctrl + V themselves >:D

Comment: also PHP is server side, so it has no access to anything on the users computer.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the clipboard is disabled by default in most browsers (for security reasons). You could try this (jQuery) but it wont work unless the user has clipboard access enabled.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(() => {
        if (typeof window.clipboardData === 'undefined') {
          alert('clipboard disabled')
        } else {
          $('#text_area').val(window.clipboardData.getData());
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I know this is very old answer, but mind fixing the formating? In the else statement in first JQuery brackets, you use both `'` and `"` in single bracket, leading to syntax error. You also didn't close your `<script>` tag on the end.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible.  Sorry.  But you can change the clipboard data with javascript, just not read it.